# CRUD operations via annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm new to Java. Can somebody explain how to use annotations and reflection for code reuse? I want to make a simple console program that implements CRUD operations on JDBC via this technology.

Comment: Why not just an ORM such as Hibernate?

Comment: It's a task from my mentor.

Comment: If the solution to your problem is more complicated than the problem you're trying to solve, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to Java, you still have at least a couple thousand hours of coding (perhaps more) before you are experienced enough to write your own code that uses reflection paired with annotations to achieve code reuse (in a sane way). It is a **very uncommon** way of writing Java programs and - as such - it is mainly used in infrastructure code: libraries and frameworks. Even if some technology expects programmers to write their own annotations, (like in BVF or CDI), they are only used within the constraints of the framework.

There is little sense in writing annotation/reflection code before you have used many such libraries and have gathered enough experience as a user of such code. And when you do, you will not need to ask questions.